# Remove all elements within a ng-repeat in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working with Angular and part of my page utilizes `ng-repeat` to display some bug tracker tickets. As part of the site, I also want to provide the ability to search tickets. I'm able to get that part working as I want, and if I'm just appending new tickets they show up fine.

However I would like to be able to, if a user searches, delete all of the  currently visible ticket divs and replace them with the search results.

My initial thinking, since I have the `ng-repeat` set as `item in tickets track by item.id`, was to just set `$scope.tickets` equal to the new data. However, this didn't cause Angular to update the DOM.

So, I tried setting `$scope.tickets` equal to an empty array and *then* setting it equal to the new data:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.tickets = [];

    $scope.tickets = data;
});
```

Still no update to the DOM, even though `console.log($scope.tickets)` shows the correct objects.

I'm aware of the method of

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    array.splice(index, 1);
});
```

to remove individual elements, but I'm not sure how I would apply that removing all of the elements.

I'll try and get a Plunkr or JSBin added to the Q soon.

What would be the proper way for me to make Angular replace all of the current elements with the new elements created from the data?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a filter in your ng-repeat expression (e.g `item in tickets track by item.id | filter : expression : comparator`)
It would do the job of hiding/showing only the divs you are searching.
Check AngularJS doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: We need to see more code context. There isn't enough shown for us to be able to know why view doesn't update. Always provide [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting `array.length = 0` 
this deletes all elements, while not removing the reference to the array, which actually seems to be the problem in your case.

but another way would be to have a additional data bag.

for example have `$scope.data.tickets` then you can reasign `tickets` as usual. important thing is, you have to reference your items using `item in data.tickets`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately, that didn't work. Any divs already existing that aren't in the new data remain there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you test `$watch`?

```
$scope.$watch('tickets', function() {
   // update data HERE
});
```